# Custom terminal command using bash_profile

Tags: terminal, bash

I am trying to make a new command which runs a shell script that takes in arguments.

So, I have the command in my .bash_profile:

```
command() {
  /Users/myname/filepath/MyScript.sh
}
```

but MyScript.sh can take in arguments. So how can I modify this code to handle arguments so that it will pass those arguments to MyScript.h?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a bash alias:

```
alias mycommand="/Users/myname/filepath/MyScript.sh $@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all parameters to command to go to MyScript.sh, then try this:

```
command() {
  /Users/myname/filepath/MyScript.sh "$@"
}
```